# Se B é um subtipo de A, por que uma coleção de B não é um subtipo de uma coleção de A?

Tags: java, tipagem, genéricos, coleção

Dados:

```
public interface A { ... }

public interface B extends A { ... }

private Set<B> bs = new HashSet<>();

RecebeA qualquerCoisa = new RecebeA(bs);
```

Por que a última linha compila se o construtor `RecebeA` for declarado como:

```
public RecebeA(Collection<? extends A> as) { ... }
```

e não compila se for declarado como

```
public RecebeA(Collection<A> as) { ... }
```

?

Se quiser fazer do segundo jeito serei obrigado a fazer a gambiarra `new RecebeA(new HashSet<>(bs));` ?

Tem solução melhor?

Comment: Editei o título, mas não sei se é exatamente a "essência" do que vc quis saber...

Comment: O título está bom, também é uma dúvida, apesar que a dúvida essencial era por que Collection<? extends Interface> funciona e Collection<Interface> não. Mas essa dúvida eu tirei nos comentários da resposta, obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso acontece porque herança em coleções não funciona da mesma maneira que funciona com classes. No próprio [tutorial da Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/subtype.html) é mencionado que:

> *In general, if `Foo` is a subtype (subclass or subinterface) of `Bar`, and `G` is some generic type declaration, it is **not** the case that `G<Foo>` is a subtype of `G<Bar>`.*

Ou seja, se `B` é um subtipo de `A` (sejam eles classes ou interfaces), **não** é verdade que um `Set<B>` é um subtipo de `Set<A>`. E isso não vale apenas para `Set`, mas para qualquer tipo genérico. É contra-intuitivo porque imaginamos que o "lógico" seria que uma coleção de `B` deveria ser um subtipo de uma coleção de `A`, se `B` for um subtipo de `A`. Mas não é.

O próprio tutorial já citado dá um exemplo parecido com o seu:

```
List<String> ls = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Object> lo = ls; // erro, não compila
```

Afinal, se `String` é um `Object`, então por que uma lista de `String` não é uma lista de `Object`? Porque se o código acima compilasse, então seria possível fazer isso:

```
lo.add(new Object()); // adicionando um Object que não é uma String
String s = ls.get(0); // ops, não vai retornar uma String
```

*Provavelmente* para evitar este tipo de situação, decidiram que o melhor é nem deixar atribuir uma lista de `String` em uma lista de `Object`.

---

No seu caso, o mesmo poderia acontecer. Suponha que eu tenho outra sub-interface de `A`:

```
public interface C extends A { ... }

public class ImplementoC implements C { ... }

public class RecebeA {
    public RecebeA(Collection<A> as) {
        as.add(new ImplementoC()); // isso compila
    }
}

...
Set<B> bs = new HashSet<>();
RecebeA qualquerCoisa = new RecebeA(bs); // isso não compila, mas vamos supor que compilasse
B b = bs.iterator().next(); // aqui seria retornado uma instância de ImplementoC (que é um C, não um B)
```

Ou seja, se fosse possível passar um `Set<B>` para o construtor que só recebe `Collection<A>`, dentro dele eu poderia adicionar qualquer implementação de `A` (mesmo que não tenha relação de subtipo com `B`), e ao tentar obter os valores do `Set<B>` eles não seriam instâncias de `B`. No caso acima, seria possível adicionar instâncias de `C` em um `Set<B>`, mesmo que `B` e `C` não sejam subtipo um do outro.

---

Curiosamente, isso aqui também não funciona:

```
public RecebeA(Collection<? extends A> as) {
    as.add(new ImplementoC()); // agora essa linha não compila
}

Set<B> bs = new HashSet<>();
RecebeA qualquerCoisa = new RecebeA(bs); // mas essa compila
```

Pois é, mesmo que o parâmetro seja declarado como `Collection<? extends A>`, eu não posso adicionar um `C` nela. Isso porque o valor recebido pode ser uma coleção de qualquer subclasse/sub-interface de `A` (como por exemplo `B`, que não tem relação de subtipo com `C`, ou seja, se a linha acima compilasse seria possível adicionar um `C` em um `Set<B>`).

---

Pegando emprestado o [exemplo do Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2745301), para ficar um pouco mais claro:

```
List<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<Dog>();
// uma lista de cachorros é uma lista de animais, certo? (não, a linha abaixo não compila)
List<Animal> animals = dogs;
// se a linha acima compilasse, seria possível fazer isso:
animals.add(new Cat()); // adicionando um gato na lista de cachorros
Dog dog = dogs.get(0); // ops, não é um cachorro
```

No caso, `Animal` seria a interface `A`, `Dog` seria a interface `B` e `Cat` seria `C`.

E se eu tiver uma classe que recebe uma lista de animais:

```
public class RecebeAnimal {
    public RecebeAnimal(Collection<Animal> c) {
        c.add(new Cat());
    }
}

...
List<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<>();
RecebeAnimal r = new RecebeAnimal(dogs); // não compila
```

Se a linha acima compilasse, eu conseguiria adicionar um gato na lista de cachorros.

Agora se eu trocar o construtor:

```
public RecebeAnimal(Collection<? extends Animal> c) {
    c.add(new Cat()); // não compila
}

...
List<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<>();
RecebeAnimal r = new RecebeAnimal(dogs); // compila
```

A última linha compila porque agora a `Collection` pode ser de qualquer subclasse de `Animal`. Mas a linha com `c.add(new Cat())` não compila, porque se compilasse ainda seria possível adicionar um gato na lista de cachorros.

A única coisa que dá pra fazer no construtor é acessar os elementos da coleção como animais: `for (Animal a : c) { etc }` (assim como no seu exemplo você poderia fazer um `for` na `Collection<? extends A>`). Claro que aí você pode usar `instanceof` e *cast* para obter tipos específicos, mas aí já depende do que você precisa fazer.

---

E como resolve? Depende. O que exatamente `RecebeA` deve receber? Uma coleção de `A`, de qualquer subtipo de `A`, de somente `B`?

Na verdade, acho que só tendo o caso concreto para saber a melhor solução. Com nomes genéricos assim, só dá para especular, mas de qualquer forma, sabendo as limitações e o funcionamento dos *wildcards*, você pode avaliar os requisitos e ver o que é melhor para o seu caso.

Comment: O caso concreto é assim: a classe `Server` instancia `SocketHandler`s. A interface `ServerListener` estende `SocketHandlerListener`. Quero passar no construtor de `SocketHandler` uma coleção de `ServerListener`s. Será que violei o princípio de substituição de Liskov?

Comment: @Piovezan Não entendi nada, que classes são essas? :-)  Quem são o `A`, `B` e `RecebeA` nessa história?

Comment: "Interface A extends B" = "Interface ServerListener extends SocketHandlerListener". "RecebeA" = "SocketHandler". Um Server possui uma lista de ServerListeners e instancia SocketHandlers, que por sua vez possui SocketHandlerListeners. Quero passar ServerListeners para o SocketHandler como se fossem SocketHandlerListeners.

Comment: A orientação a objetos disso aí deve estar toda errada :D

Comment: `ServerListener` observa o Server, portanto tem métodos onStarted(), onPortBusy(int port), onStopped(), onNewHandler(SocketHandler handler). Já `SocketHandlerListener` observa o SocketHandler, portanto tem métodos onAuthenticated(Collection<String> tokens), onDisconnect(Collection<String> tokens, String causa). Eu assumi que quem está interessado nos eventos de Server também está interessado nos eventos de SocketHandler.

Comment: @Piovezan Bom, acho que ou você muda o `SocketHandler` para ter uma lista `List<? extends SocketHandlerListener>` (e receber isso no construtor, aí vc consegue passar um `List<ServerListener>` para ele), ou vc faz a gambiarra mesmo: `new SocketHandler(new ArrayList<SocketHandlerListener>(listeners))` - supondo que `listeners` é a lista do `Server` (um `List<ServerListener>`).

Comment: ...que são as duas opções que eu propus na pergunta. Não tem jeito melhor de fazer não então, né? Só remodelando, imagino.

Comment: @Piovezan Da forma que está, acho que essas são as opções. Mas se puder rever o modelo, acho que é uma boa. Será que `ServerListener` deveria mesmo ser um subtipo de `SocketHandlerListener`?

Comment: É, essa herança de tipo não está cheirando muito bem. Beleza, resposta aceita. :)

Comment: Só me tire uma última dúvida, se já não estiver na resposta (aí me fale que eu releio), por que `Collection<? extends Interface>` dá certo e `Collection<Interface>` não?

Comment: @Piovezan Porque `Collection<Tipo>` indica que vai receber uma coleção somente de `Tipo`, e `Collection<? extends Tipo>` indica que a coleção pode ser de qualquer subtipo de `Tipo`. Veja a seção "Bounded Wildcards": https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html - como eu disse, herança em coleções funciona meio diferente e muitas vezes é contraintuitivo, mas acho que fizeram assim por causa das consequências mencionadas na resposta (evitar ser possível adicionar um gato na lista de cachorros, etc)