# Dúvida sobre polimorfismo

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, polimorfismo

Olá, boa tarde, eu tenho uma pergunta relacionada a polimorfismo.

Suponha que eu tenho um objeto `Casa` que implementa `Imovel` onde `Imovel` tem um método `getValorIptu()` e Casa tem um atributo `nomeProprietario`.

Eu gostaria de ter um método que apenas calculasse o valor total dos IPTUS de uma Lista de Imóveis e tbm um método que aplica, ou calcula, um imposto a um imóvel.

Por que eu não posso enviar uma lista de casas para um método que aceita uma lista de imóveis?
E, já que eu não posso mandar fazer o que disse na pergunta acima, pq eu posso enviar uma casa para um método que aceita um imóvel?

Eu tentei usar mais ou menos a lógica que existe quando se vai fazer um método que aceita um `List<?>` e ele também aceita uma `ArrayList` pq a mesma implementa `List`. Da mesma forma, `Casa` implementa `Imovel` mas dá erro.

Há alguma outra forma de fazer?

A intenção
é que eu  possa criar um método que seja pontual no que ele vai utilizar, no caso do método que recebe uma lista, ele apenas usaria o `getValorIptu()`
e não precisaria de `nomeProprietario`

Na imagem abaixo consta o código de teste que fiz, mas continuei sem entender

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Se B é um subtipo de A, por que uma coleção de B não é um subtipo de uma coleção de A?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/470676/se-b-%c3%a9-um-subtipo-de-a-por-que-uma-cole%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-b-n%c3%a3o-%c3%a9-um-subtipo-de-uma-cole%c3%a7%c3%a3o)

Comment: Basicamente, quando há listas (e qualquer outra coleção envolvida), as coisas se complicam (só porque `A` é um subtipo de `B`, não quer dizer que `List<A>` seja um subtipo de `List<B>`). Além da pergunta já sugerida acima, que explica o problema, [tem essa também](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8679/112052)

Answer (score 0):

Marcos, pegando um gancho naquilo que os outros colegas já comentaram o que você poderia fazer seria converter a sua List de **Casas** em uma Lista de **Imoveis**.

Exemplo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Casa c = new Casa();    
    List<Imovel> lm = new ArrayList<>();        
    lm.add(c);              
    Main.aplicarVariosImpostos(lm);     

}

static void aplicarVariosImpostos(List<Imovel> testList) {      
    for (Imovel i: testList) {
        System.out.println(i.getValorIptu()); 
    }
}
```